# How to add apps in "COMING SOON" section of Google play?

Tags: android, google-play

How do I pre-register an Android app to be featured in the coming soon section on the Android Play Store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is a customer service question; see : [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746). Has no sign of being a programming question but rather a marketing related query.

Answer (score 2):

You have to [contact](https://support.google.com/googleplay/contact/developer_profile_survey/) Google Business Development's managers to set-up a pre-register campaign.

Comment: This does answer the question. That is precisely the step you take to accomplish the goal he seeks.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.

Comment: No worries! Though I do agree with the consensus that this question does not fit the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This answer contains the step needed, the link is for reference. The literal steps to answer the question are "Contact Google Business Development's managers". That is how you accomplish the goal he seeks. The link is merely a reference to the contact page.